# Unable to load objects in template with include tag in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to display objects in home.html template , The object is mainly in laglist template. I used the include tag to carry out the operation but it's not working. Below are my codes:

laglist.html

```
   {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block lag %}
        <h2>Lam </h2>

        {% for leggo in leggos  %}
           <p><a href= "{% url halldetail leggo.id %}" >{{ leggo.name }}</a><p>
      <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{leggo.thumbnail_1.url}}" width="83" height="78"> <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{leggo.thumbnail_2.url}}" width="83" height="78" />

        <li>{{ leggo.state }}</li>
         {% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}
```

View for laglist:

```
    def lag_view(request):
        leggos=Fin.objects.filter(state='venu')
        for leggo in leggos:
            print leggo.id
        return render_to_response('laglist.html',  {'leggos':leggos,'leggo':leggo,'Fin':Fin},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

home.html

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
 {% block content %}

   <p> {% include 'laglist.html' %} </p>
 {% endblock %}
```

view for home

```
 def homp(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Your laglist.html and home.html both extends from base.html. Probably, that doesn't work well when you include such template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a fairly common misconception, although I don't understand why.

Views render templates, not the other way round. A template has no connection to a view, and including a template does not call a view.

If you want to include a template along with some Python code, you will need to write a custom template tag - probably an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to pass `leggos` dictionary to your home view for it to work. so try this in your home view.

```
def home(request):
    data = {}
    data['leggos'] = Fin.objects.filter(state='venu')
    return render_to_response('home.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and then in laglist.html try this:

```
{% if leggos %}
    {% for leggo in leggos %}
        <p> {{ leggo }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p> Sorry, No Leggos Found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After trying it, It's returning "Sorry no leggos found" what's wrong?

Comment: it seems that leggos object being passed to the template is empty or None. Make sure it has some results.